# Integrate $I=\int_0^{\pi} \left(\cos(\theta)\right)^n \cos(p\theta) d\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, chebyshev-polynomials

Is there any standard solution or way to solve the following integration

$$I=\int_0^{\pi} \left(\cos(\theta)\right)^n \cos(p\theta) d\theta$$

where, $n=0, 1, 2,\dots$ and $p=0, 1, 2,\dots$ and $p> n$

Comment: I am not sure that the inequality $i>n$ adds much to the discussion :)

Comment: One can use reduction formula.

Comment: What is $i$ supposed to be? It does not appear on the integral.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. it should be $p>n$

Comment: Using the Vieta's formula for $\cos (p \theta)$ simplies the stuff. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: residue theorem will do the job

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Using the complex representation with $z=e^{i\theta}$,

$$I=-i\int_1^{-1}\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}2\right)^n\frac{z^p+z^{-p}}2\frac{dz}z\
=-\frac i{2^{n+1}}\int_1^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\left(z^{2k-n+p-1}+z^{2k-n-p-1}\right)dz.$$

Then for $m\ne-1$,

$$\int_0^\pi z^mdz=\left.\frac{z^{m+1}}{m+1}\right|_1^{-1}=-\frac2{m+1}$$ for even $m$ and $0$ otherwise, and

$$\int_0^\pi z^{-1}dz=\left.\log z\right|_1^{-1}=i\pi.$$

Logically, all imaginary terms should vanish, leaving either $0$ or $$\binom n{(n+p)/2}\dfrac\pi{2^{n+1}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> \begin{align}
> I_{np} &\equiv
> \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{p\theta}\,\dd\theta =
> \half\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^{n}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{p\theta}\,\dd\theta:\ ?.
> \quad 
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
> \ds{n \in \braces{0,1,2\ldots}}
> \\
> \ds{p \in \mathbb{Z}}
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{I_{np}} & =
\half\,\Re\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^{n}\pars{\theta}\expo{\ic p\theta}\,\dd\theta =
\half\,\Re\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,\pars{z^{2} + 1 \over 2z}^{n}z^{p}
\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\\[4mm] & =
{1 \over 2^{n + 1}}\,\Im\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,
{\pars{1 + z^{2}}^{n} \over z^{n - p + 1}}\,\dd z =
{1 \over 2^{n + 1}}\,\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,{\dd z \over z^{n - p - 2k + 1}}
\\[4mm] & =
{1 \over 2^{n + 1}}\,\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
2\pi\ic\bracks{\vphantom{\large A} n -p - 2k + 1 = 1}\quad
\mbox{where}\ \bracks{\cdots}\ \mbox{is an}\ \ul{Iverson\ Bracket}\,.
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\mbox{Then,}\quad\color{#f00}{I_{np}} & =
{\pi \over 2^{n}}{n \choose \pars{n - p}/2}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}
\bracks{{n - p \over 2} = k}
\\[4mm] & =
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{ccl}
\ds{{\pi \over 2^{n}}{n \choose \pars{n - p}/2}} & \mbox{if} &
\ds{0 \leq {n - p \over 2} \leq n\quad\mbox{and}\quad{n - p \over 2}\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{0}&&\mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

---

With $\color{#f00}{\ds{n\ \in\ \braces{0,1,2,\ldots}}}$ and
$\color{#f00}{\ds{p \in \mathbb{Z}}}$:
$$
\color{#f00}{I_{np}} \equiv
\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{p\theta}\,\dd\theta =
\color{#f00}{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{ccl}
\ds{{\pi \over 2^{n}}{n \choose \pars{n - p}/2}} & \mbox{if} &
\ds{n\ \geq\ \verts{p}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
{n - p \over 2}\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{0}&&\mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.}
$$